# SSRS Page Break on a grouping

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In SSRS within a matrix you can page break by a group easily.
What if you have multiple tables and matrix on the same report, but wanted each to page break by the same group?

So you select multiple retailers, and you want to display each table for that retailer and then page break to show the next retailer in the same matrix.

So the three tables below need to page break after every retailer, is this possible?

[image]

Comment: I have resolved this now, just put the tables into a list and group on the retailer.

Answer (score 1):

If your three tables have the same dataset, simply add them into a parent table, which has a retailer group handling the page break.

If your tables have different datasets I'm sorry that I don't have a solution for you.